# Can't login to windows7 and ubuntu (dual boot)

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows-7

it has been a week since i didn't restart my PC so i thought it would be a good idea to restart it while i was on windows. but when it restarts nothing happens. it shows mainboard screen then screen goes black where it normally would show 'choose your operating system' screen.

luckly i had ubuntu on my pendrive, it started without any problem. i can open files on my hdd, i think there is no hardware problem, everything seems working good.

i didn't make any critical change while i was on windows as far as i remember other then installing and uninstalling softwares. i haven't been using ubuntu for a while so there shouldn't be problem caused by ubuntu.

does the situation look familiar to you? What's the problem, any idea, suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which is the boot manager? GRUB(2) or the windows' one?
If you want to use grub - get the boot-repair iso and burn it on a cd: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_:_get_a_CD_including_Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_%3a_get_a_CD_including_Boot-Repair)

Comment: i dont know which one it is but first i installed windows then installed ubuntu.

Comment: actually, it didn't solved it completely. i restarted the pc and exact same problem again. i am using autodesk maya, all this problems began after i installed maya on my pc. boot-repair said "Flexnet detected" it repaired then i successfully booted to windows. i opened maya then restarted the pc and very same thing again. isn't there a permanent solution?

Comment: What is "Autodesk maya"? edit: I saw. Remove flexnet (or what uses it.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Ubuntu using wubi ,where you installs Ubuntu on the windows partition OR did you install on a seperate partition ?  Could  be either a corrupt bootloader or some corruption on the windows parition . Either ways you could do some diagnosis  using the Windows 7 rescue disk and perform one or more of  the follwing from the resuce console

1. Perform chkdsk
2. If required restore fix the master boot record  using fixboot /mbr

Comment: no, i didn't use wubi. first i installed windows then installed ubuntu on seperate partition.